# How can I change a specific string of an array of objects with TextInput in react native using react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, use-state, react-native-textinput

I have created a button that whenever is touched, it adds this object, {problema: '', solucion: '', key: Math.random(), index: index+1}, to this useState array, const [data, setData] = useState ([]). The constant data is used in a Flatlist that contains two TextInput, one for changing the string problema and the other to change the string solucion. My problem is that when you touch several times the button, the constant data will contain several object and I dont know how to change that specific string based on the TextInput that you use.

```
{
    
    let [index, setIndex] = useState(-1);

    let passingValue = { problema: '', solucion: '', key: Math.random().toString(), index: index+1  }

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    const onPressPlus = () => {
        setIndex(index + 1)
        setData(prevState => [...prevState, passingValue])
        console.log(data);
    } 

    return (
       
        <View>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressPlus}>
                <AntDesign name='pluscircle'/>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    renderItem={itemData => (
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
                            <View> 
                                <TextInput
                                    placeholder="Escribe tu problema"
                                    placeholderTextColor='black'
                                    value={itemData.item.problema}
                                    onChangeText={(e) => { /* I dont know how to change the value of this specific itemData.item.problema with setData()*/ }}
                                    multiline={true}
                                    numberOfLines={2}
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View>
                                <TextInput
                                    placeholder="Escribe tu problema"
                                    placeholderTextColor='black'
                                    value={itemData.item.solucion}
                                    onChangeText={(e) => { /* I dont know how to change the value of this specific itemData.item.solucion with setData() */ }}
                                    multiline={true}
                                    numberOfLines={2}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        )}
                    keyExtractor={itemData => itemData.key}
                />   
            </View>
        </View>
                    
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightforward solution is to pass the index of `renderItem` into the function,  and write over the array

```
onChangeText={str => setData(prev => {
                       prev[itemData.index] = { ...prev[itemData.index],solucion: str }
                       return prev
                       }
      }
```

Anyhow, it seems like you want to have obj like data stored in array (with `key` value), consider treating your data as object, and render `FlatList` of `Object.entries`

A better approach, and for not calling hugh `setState` on the whole list on each iteration, is to split `renderItem` into stand alone components, while question come as prop and answer is independent `state`, and when calling the `onSubmit` pass the inside values (what will require some `state-managment` architecture, `form` (can implementwith libary) or using local `ref`s or `context`, if its just one time call from component to api)

Comment: Every time I use e.target.value I get the error that undefined is not an object. How can I fix that? Thank you for the help anyways

Comment: Sorry, `e.target.value` is the web usage of `input`, editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 states to hold value of 2 input fields

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const [problem, setProblem] = useState('')
const [solution, setSolution] = useState('')
```

You use 2 functions below to get the value of input fields

```js
const onChangeProblem = e => {
    value = e.target.value
    setProblem(value)
}

const onChangeSolution = e => {
    value = e.target.value
    setSolution(value)
}
```

Pass this function as below

```js
<TextInput
    ...
    onChangeText={onChangeProblem}
/>
...
<TextInput
    ...
    onChangeText={onChangeSolution}
/>
```